# Re-publishing an ASP.NET Web Application While Site is Live

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I am trying to get a grasp on how to handle updates to a live, functioning ASP.NET (2.0 or greater) Application while there are users on the site.

For example, suppose SO is an ASP.NET Web Application project. The project code compiles down to the single .DLL in the BIN folder. Now, there are constantly users on SO, so what would happen to users' actions/sessions if you would use the Visual Studio .NET "Publish" feature (or just FTP everything again manually) while they are using the site?

Would creating an ASP.NET Web Site, instead, alleviate any problems that may or may not exist with the scenario above? I am beginning to develop a web site as a user-driven Web Application, and I want to make sure that my inexperience with this would not potentially annoy the [potentially] many users that I [want to] have 24/7.

EDIT: Sorry, I should have put this in a more exact context. Assume that this site is being hosted by a web hosting service with monthly fees. I won't be managing the server itself, just what the web host allows as a user of their services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing to the asp.net web site model won't have any effect, as the recycle will also happen, some of changes that trigger it for sure: web.config, global.asax, app_code.

After the recycle, user will still be logged in because asp.net will just validate the syntax. That is given you use a fixed machine key, otherwise it will change on each recycle. This is something you want to do anyway as other stuff can break if the key change across requests i.e. viewstate validation, embedded resources (decryption of the url fails).

If you can put the session out of process, like in sql server, you will avoid loosing the session. If you can't, your code will have to consider that. There are plenty of scenarios where you can avoid using session, and others were you can wrap it and re-retrieve the info if the session was cleaned. This should leave you with a handful specific cases that you know can give trouble to the users, so for those you do some of the suggestions others have already made.

Answer (score 5):

I create two Web sites in IIS. One is the production Web site, and the other is a static Web site with an HttpHandler that sends all requests to a single static "We're updating" HTML page served with an HTTP 503 Service Unavailable. Typically the update Web site is turned off. When it's time to update, we stop the production Web site, start the update Web site, and now we can fiddle with the production Web site all we want without worrying about DLLs being locked or worker processes needing to be spun down.

I started doing this because

- App_Offline.htm really does not work well in Web Gardens, which we use.
- App_Offline.htm serves its page as 404, which is bad if you're down for a meaningful period of time.
- We can start the upgraded production Web site with modified settings (only listening on localhost), where we can do a last-minute acceptance/verification that everything is working before we flip the switch, turning off the update Web site and re-enabling the production Web site.

Things this does not solve include

- Any maintenance that requires a restart of the server--you still have downtime where no page is served.
- Any maintenance that diddles with the .NET runtime, like upgrading to the latest service pack.

Other approaches I've seen include

- Having two servers. Send all load balancing requests to one server, upgrade the other one; then rinse and repeat. Most of us don't have this luxury.
- Creating multiple bin directories, like bin-1.0.0.0 and bin-1.1.0.0 and telling ASP.NET which bin directory to use in the web.config file. (One advantage of this is that reverting to a previous binary is just editing a config file. A disadvantage is that it's harder to revert resources that don't end up in your binaries, like templates and images and such.) I don't remember how this actually worked--I think the application did some late assembly loading in its Global.asax based on its own web.config section (since you touched the web.config, the app had restarted, so it was okay).

If you find a better way, let me know!

Comment: Very good info, thanks. Not only that, your answer pointed out something my original question was lacking. I've edited my question to add in the constraint of the site being on a "$?.??/month" web host. I won't have access to IIS, etc. But this answer WILL help me when at work ;)

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you set the status code for a **static** HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to deploy your application into a load balanced environment (web farm).
When deploying a new version you would use the load balancer to redirect requests to the server you are not deploying to.

Answer (score 1):

[App_offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) is great solution for this I think.

in SO we see application currently unavailable page when a deployment begins.

Comment: One thing to note about App_offline.htm is it doesn't work in a Web Garden. (Well, it does, but the worker process only spins down on the next page hit, so you have to refresh a bunch of times and hope you got round-robined between them all....) FYI since I learned this the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how SO handles it.. But we usually put a holding page. So what ever the user has done (adding question or answering questions) does not get updated. As soon as he updates something he will see a holding page asking him to try after sometime.

And if I am the user I usually press the back button to make sure what I entered is saved in the browser history so that I can post later.

Some site use use are in clustered environment so I take one server offline and inform the load balancer that she will not be available and once I make sure that the new version is working fine I make it live.. I do the same thing for the next server.

Do we have any other option?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a technical solution, but set up a scheduled maintenance window.  You can annoucement in advance giving your user base fair warning that there is a possiblity that the application will not be available during that time frame.